Finding rank of matrix $A$.

Let $A_{n×n}$
=$((a_{ij}))$
n≥3
, where $a_{ij}=(b_i^2−b_j^2)$
, i,j=1,2,…,n
for some distinct real numbers $b_1,b_2,…,b_n$
.
Then what is $\rho (A)$
?


My attempt:
A can be written as difference of two matrices of rank $1$ i.e.
$A=B-C$ where,$B=(b_i^2)_{ij}$ and $C=(b_j^2)_{ij}$.
So $\rho (B)=\rho (C)=1$.
Now as $\rho (B-C)\leq\rho (B)+\rho (C)$.
Therefore, $\rho (A)= \rho (B-C)\leq {2}$.
Can we find lower bound for the $\rho (A)$?


Have you excluded $\rho=0$? [Given that $n\geqslant 3$ and the $b_i$ are distinct that ought to be easy.] Have you excluded $\rho=1$.[Given that $n\geqslant 3$ and the $b_i$ are distinct that ought to be possible.]

@ancientmathematician Sir,I have not excluded any possibility.

Surely you can eliminate the possibility that $\rho=0$? Which matrix has rank $0$?

@ancientmathematician zero matrix has rank 0 but here $b_i$ are all distinct so it can not be a zero matrix.

Good. But you need rather that the only matrix of rank $0$ is the zero matrix; and since $n\geqslant 3$ and $b_1^2=b_i^2$ has only two roots, the case $\rho=0$  can't occur. I suggest you do the case $\rho=1$ yourself.

@ancientmathematician by the same logic ?
